# Creating singleband pseudocolor ramp displaying colors based on values using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, cartography, color-ramp

With QGIS desktop, I'm trying to create a ramp to a DEM using a singleband pseudocolor style. I have created a ramp with 15 different colours and values as well.

I can't find the option to apply those automatically to the DEM, basically to display the elevation based on the values specified... (everything below 0 should be blue, and so on).

Is the position of each class of the ramp should reflect the ratio of the elevation?

[image: singleband pseudocolor]

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the values by double-clicking in the values-column on the left side to apply irregular intervals that fit better your data, see:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's what I've done... but apparently it's not based on the value. 

So your suggestion is to teak the values manually until the point to reach the desirable colours...
I'm new to QGIS/ArcGIS, however it sounds weird to me that they didn't implemented that option :)

Comment: I'm not sure about the problem - on your screenshot, you set `0` next to green - and thus the ocean is green, as you defined it. Changing the values should change the distribution of the colors accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I still don't get it but somehow I found a solution.
I had to create an intermediate colour for the sea (0) and start from that 0.1, 100, 200, etc.
Another point was to switch the Mode to Continuous and to check that the Label was matching automatically the Value...

Many thanks everyone for your time and answers.

[image]